# Shopify Order Edit: XXX was not added because it's already on the order

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a new product variant with API. The new variant will include the total price and weight of several variants. The format is attached

[image]

You can see that the buy 4 vans is the new variant. When the order is paid, the variants included are added as free items. I tried to add with [orderEditAddVariant](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/orders/ordereditaddvariant) and then [orderEditAddLineItemDiscount](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/orders/ordereditaddlineitemdiscount) with the [new Order Edit API](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/edit-an-existing-order-with-admin-api).

It's working well until someone tries to buy one of the items separately. The order edit cannot commit. Afer orderEditAddVariant, it gives an error and stop here.

after addVariantsToOrder: result =

{'data': {'orderEditAddVariant': {'calculatedOrder': None, 'userErrors': [{'field': ['id'], 'message': "**VANS      | ERA 59 (DESERT COWBOY) - 9 / light_brown was not added because it's already o     n the order."**}]}}, 'extensions': {'cost': {'requestedQueryCost': 16, 'actualQueryCost': 10, 'throttleStatus': {'maximumAvailable': 1000.0, 'currentlyAvailable': 90, 'restoreRate': 50.0}}}}

How can I resolve this? Did anyone try to fix it?

I also try to open a thread on Shopify community & ask the Partner support but have no luck

When I added the item manually in Shopify admin - Order Edit, I can successfully add the item. Theeefore, I don't know why it's not permitted in the GraphQL admin API.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. From [the doc](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/orders/ordereditaddvariant), just add allowDuplicates: true and the edit will be permitted.